# AndEngine - Dragging a sprite that has a path modifier registered to it

Tags: andengine

I'm looking to be able to drag a sprite that is currently on a path from a path modifier.  Currently, I have sprites on a path, and I have stationary sprites that are draggable.  However, simply overriding the sprite's `onAreaTouched` doesn't work until the sprite completes its path.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see those possibilities:

- you could call `clearEntityModifiers();` in the `onAreaTouched` of your sprite. This will kill **all** modifiers you registered to the sprite (so your pathmodifier but also any `AlphaModifier` or else).
- or you can call `unregisterEntityModifier( yourPathModifier );`

hope this helps.
regards

Christoph

Comment: I put a Log.i inside the `onAreaTouched` event and nothing registers until after the path is clear.  So trying to call those methods will not work.  My only thought right now is to add a transparent sprite over-top of the path modified sprite (which updates with the game loop) to utilize its `onAreadTouch` but this seems very clunky....

Comment: that's odd... maybe there is something else blocking the onAreaTouched. It is definitely possible to touch a sprite when it is moving and to kill the modifier at any time – I did it before, although I didn't make the sprite draggable like you do. But that shouldn't be the point. Maybe you can add code to the post, like for example your onAreaTouched and the part where you create the PathModifier.

Comment: It was my mistake, I added the `Log.i` to the wrong `onAreaTouched`.  This did work, thanks!